# Non-roundcorner menu

Tags: css, fxml

In default menu in JavaFX 2.*, menu tab is rounded. How to change it to rectangle shape?

I've tried with CSS but I cannot figure out which component to change.

Comment: CSS: `border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;` for example, and you can add some variations for earlier versions of Chrome and Mozilla ... but this won't work in <IE9

Comment: firebug... that's all you need to know. It is absolutely great at figuring out what css is affecting what element.

Comment: Im using JavaFX in desktop application, so firebug its not the answer.